# Where need commma in appsscript.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-10, clasp

I have set up for clasp refering to the [document](https://github.com/google/clasp/blob/master/docs/run.md#setup-instructions). 
I found an error in a file named appsscript.json. (Prerequisites in the document)
The error is: Expected comma json(514) [8,3]
Please tell me resolution.

```
{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Tokyo",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"

  "executionApi": {
    "access": "ANYONE"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code bellow mising comma:

```
"runtimeVersion": "V8"
```

replace code:

```
"runtimeVersion": "V8",
```

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply. I resolved when comma was added after "V8". Thanks a lot.